# Python Selenium pull href info out of find_elements_by_partial_link_text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im working on pulling some data from a website, I can successfully surf to the page that lists all the updated data from the day before, but now I need to iterate through all the links, and save the source of each page to a file.

Once in a file I want to use BeautifulSoup to better arrange the data so I can parse through it.

```
#learn.py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url1 = 'https://odyssey.tarrantcounty.com/default.aspx'
date = '07/31/2014'
option_by_date = "6"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url1)
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Case')

#follow link
continue_link.click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='SearchBy']/option[text()='Date Filed']").click()
#fill in dates in form
from_date = driver.find_element_by_id("DateFiledOnAfter")
from_date.send_keys(date)
to_date = driver.find_element_by_id("DateFiledOnBefore")
to_date.send_keys(date)

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id('SearchSubmit')
submit_button.click()

link_list = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('2014')
```

link_list should be a list of the applicable links, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Get all links that have `href` attribute starting with `CaseDetail.aspx?CaseID=`, [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) would help here:

```
# get the list of links
links = [link.get_attribute('href') 
         for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td/a[starts-with(@href, "CaseDetail.aspx?CaseID=")]')]
for link in links:
    # follow the link
    driver.get(link)

    # parse the data
    print driver.find_element_by_class_name('ssCaseDetailCaseNbr').text
```

Prints:

```
Case No. 2014-PR01986-2
Case No. 2014-PR01988-1
Case No. 2014-PR01989-1
...
```

Note that you don't need to save the pages and parse them via `BeautifulSoup`. `Selenium` itself is pretty powerful in [navigating and extracting the data](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) out of the webpages.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like we're on the right track.  But that would just show me the case numbers correct?  I think what I'm trying to do is create a list of the links, then open each one and go through the text (I'll give it a shot parsing with selenium)

Comment: @Mike82 yup, the case number is just an example - you should elaborate that `parse the data` step. The idea is correct, yeah. Hope it helps.

Comment: I now see that this code opens each link, thanks.  I missed the     driver.get(link) when reading it the first time.  I'll figure out how to open each in a new window later.  Now, when on the final page, I want to pull out all the names and addresses, that's simple to do with Selenium?

Comment: @Mike82 yup, use it's powerful [API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html), check [`Locating Elements`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) section too. Feel free to create separate SO questions if you need help or would have difficulties. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch web elements using their tag name. If you want to fetch all the links in a web page, I would use find_elements_by_tag_name().

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
link_urls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
source_dict = dict()
for url in link_urls:
    driver.get(url)
    source = driver.page_source #this will give you page source
    source_dict[url] = source

#source_dict dictionary will contain the source code you wanted for each url with the url as the key.
```